# Spring boot with AngularJS is not working with routing from Spring Controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I have started a simple app with AngulaJS in the fronend and Spring MVC behind with Spring boot.

This is my Spring controller

```
@RestController
public class ConsumerController {

@Autowired
private ConsumerRepository consumerRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@RequestParam("consumerEmail") String consumerEmail) {

    consumerRepository.findByConsumerEmail(consumerEmail);
    return "home";
}
```

}

I get the username and password from front end and call this API through ANgularJS as shown below.

```
    $scope.login = function() {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('consumerEmail', $scope.emailID)
    console.log(data)
    $http.post('login', data, {
        withCredentials : false,
        transformRequest : angular.identity,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : undefined
        }
    }).success(function(resp) {
        $location.path('#/home');
    });
```

Here is my routing in Angular

```
abc.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl : "index.html",
    controller : "productController"
}).when('/home', {
    templateUrl : "/views/home.html",
    controller : "productController"
}).when('/login', {
    templateUrl : "/views/home.html",
    controller : "productController"
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
});
```

The issue is I receive the username in my Spring controller but when I try to return to "home" It just fails with the message below. I am not sure if I am returning it in a correct way from Spring controller.

This is what I see in the Spring DEBUG mode

```
2016-10-02 10:43:20.637 DEBUG 21936 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Written [home] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@8aa5ab4]
2016-10-02 10:43:20.637 DEBUG 21936 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
```

Any guidance will be helpful. I have done the same without the spring boot and it worked good

Comment: Your controller is a REST controller, so its methods are supposed to return data, not to forward to a view. And the routing of an angular, single-page application is done by angular, at client-side, in the browser. Not by the server by serving a new page.

Comment: So you mean to say it will work @Controller and not with @RestController?
So In this case, I should return a object by default. Is that correct?

Comment: No. I mean that since you're doing a single-page angular application, you shouldn't have views on the server. Going from page to page (or from route to route, if you prefer), is done at client side, by angular. Your web backend is just there to provide REST service, taking data as argument, and returning data, not HTML pages. Read a basic angular tutorial.

Comment: Ok I get you.. I manage all my routing in Angular as I have mentioned in my post using @routeProvider. In this case, I changed my code to return an model Object in the same method and I get the error below,

2016-10-02 12:31:19.477 DEBUG 11632 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public com.boot.model.Consumer com.boot.controller.ConsumerController.login(java.lang.String)]: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: Here is my code after changing, should I mention that it produces json.
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public Consumer login(@RequestParam("consumerEmail") String consumerEmail) { 
  Consumer consumer = consumerRepository.findByConsumerEmail(consumerEmail);
  return consumer;
 }

Comment: You could try to return a ResponseEntity.ok() from your controller, to return a 200 ok, since  you are not interested in any result from the controller

Comment: I tried to return that and dont see any difference. I have removed the return object as String and replaced with model object and tried, even then it errors